# Can I use "HTTP authorization" in HTTPS protocol?

Tags: php, http, http-authentication

Can I Use HTTP authorization in HTTPS protocol?

I mean I will use following code in PHP.

```
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin authorization\"");
header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
```

and

```
echo $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
echo $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: Yes, you can. Should work fine.

Comment: @arkascha Because I don't have SSL now. I'm just developer, and I can not access to the server.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question!

Comment: Then setup a local http server and use a self signed certificate. Takes about 5 minutes and you learn a lot.

Comment: @arkascha Takes about 5 minutes if you know how. But yes, you learn a lot by learning how to make one work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. HTTP is HTTP even if you put it through a secure tunnel.

Comment: Thank you for answer my queston!